# How to get multiple checkbox values and update to server in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am posting my full code what I am trying. I am trying to get values from multiple checkbox and I have to send in `OnButtonClick()` function. If the value is true its Y else N I have to send . But I am not able to check the check boxes. Nor unchecked them. Please help I tried something but not succeeded. Please help me with this. It will great help for me .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { ImageBackground, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, View, Platform, Image } from 'react-native';
    import { Button, Text, Item, Input, Icon, Form, ListItem, CheckBox, Body, List } from 'native-base';
    import Header from '../../ui/header';
    import TextFieldTypeClear from '../../ui/textFieldTypeClear';
    import SelectField from '../../ui/selectField';
    import { PrimaryBtn } from '../../ui/buttons';
    import BG from '../../../images/bg.jpg';
    import styles from '../../simSwap/SimSwap.style';
    import { RegularText, SmallText } from '../../ui/text';
    import { ACCOUNT_OWNER,ADDRESS,CYCLE,EMAIL,PHONE,PERIODICITY,CURRENCY,LANGUAGE,EDIT,MAIL,FAX,POST,SMS,WHATSAPP } from '../../../images';
    import _ from 'lodash';

    const styless = {
      icon:{
        marginRight:5, marginTop:3
      },
      label:{
        fontSize:14, color:'grey'
      }
    }

    const Label = ({img, textLabel}) =>{
      return (
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
          <Image style={styless.icon} source={img}/>
          <Text style={styless.label}>{textLabel}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }

    class UpdateBillPreferences extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const {navigation,clmmasterData} =this.props;
        this.state = {
          title: 'Update Bill Preferences',
          mobile: navigation.state.params.customer.service.serviceNumber,
          icon: 'sim',
          email:'',
          smsNum:'',
          faxNum:'',
          languageAndCurrecny:{
            preferredLanguage: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].billingPreferenceDetails.presentationLanguageCode,
            preferredCurrency: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].billingPreferenceDetails.preferedCurrencyCode,
          },
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {

      }

      OnButtonClick = async (preferredLanguage, preferredCurrency,email,smsNum,faxNum) => {
        const { OnButtonClick } = this.props;
        await OnButtonClick(preferredLanguage, preferredCurrency,email,smsNum,faxNum);
        this.setState({
          preferredCurrency:'',
          preferredLanguage:'',
          email :'',
          smsNum :'',
          faxNum :''

        })
      }
      languageChanged = (key, val) => {
        this.handleChange({ field: "preferredLanguage" }, val);
      };

      handleChange = (props, e) => {
        let tempObj = this.state.languageAndCurrecny;
        tempObj[props.field] = e;
        this.setState({ preferredLanguage: tempObj });
      };

      render() {
        let { title, mobile, icon,languageAndCurrecny } = this.state;
        const { navigation,clmmasterData} = this.props;
        const {billingAddressDetails,billingPreferenceDetails} = navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0];
       const {masterData , language} = clmmasterData;
        let submitBtn = { label: 'Submit', OnSubmit: this.onSubmit };

        let currencyData=[];
        masterData.preferredCurrency.map(({ code: value, name: label }) => {
          currencyData.push({ value, label });
        });

        let languageData=[];
        masterData.language.map(({ code: value, name: label }) => {
          languageData.push({ value, label });
        });

        return (
          <ImageBackground source={BG} style={styles.imgBG}>
          <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View>
                <Header title={title} subtitle={mobile} icon={icon} navigation={navigation}/>
              </View>

                <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                  <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
                    <Form style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                      <SelectField
                        label="Presentation Language"
                        node="presentationLanguage"
                        options={languageData}
                        value={languageAndCurrecny.preferredLanguage}
                        onChange={this.languageChanged}
                        that={this}
                        setIcon={true}
                        img="LANGUAGE"
                      />

                      <SelectField
                        label="Preferred Currency"
                        options={currencyData}
                        value={languageAndCurrecny.preferredCurrency}
                        node="preferredCurrency"
                        onChange={this.languageChanged}
                        that={this}
                        setIcon={true}
                        img="CURRENCY"
                      />
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'column', marginBottom:15}}>
                        <View>
                          <Text style={{ color: 'grey', marginBottom: 15, marginTop:10, fontSize:14 }}>Preference</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', marginLeft:-10}}>
                          <View style={{flex:1}}>
                          <CheckBox color="#00678f" checked={billingPreferenceDetails.isBillByPost === "Y" ? true : false}  onPress={() =>this.handleChange()}/>
                          </View>
                          <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>Post</Text>
                          </View>
                          <View style={{flex:1}}>
                          <CheckBox color="#00678f" checked={billingPreferenceDetails.isBillByEmail === "Y" ? true : false} onPress={() =>this.handleChange()}/>
                          </View>
                          <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>Email</Text>
                          </View>
                          <View style={{flex:1}}>
                          <CheckBox color="#00678f" checked={billingPreferenceDetails.isBillBySms === "Y" ? true : false}  onPress={() =>this.handleChange()}/>
                          </View>
                          <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>SMS</Text>
                          </View>
                          <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <CheckBox color="#00678f" checked={billingPreferenceDetails.isBillByFax === "Y" ? true : false}  onPress={() =>this.handleChange()}/>
                          </View>
                          <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>FAX</Text>
                          </View>

                        </View>
                      </View>

                      <View style={{flexDirection:'column', marginBottom:15}}>
                        <View style={{marginTop:10, marginBottom:10, marginLeft:-3}}>
                          <Label img={ADDRESS} textLabel="Address"/>
                        </View>
                        <View>
                        <RegularText style={{ fontWeight: 'normal' }} text={`${billingAddressDetails.address1}, ${billingAddressDetails.address2}, ${billingAddressDetails.cityName}, ${billingAddressDetails.state}, ${billingAddressDetails.country}`} textColor="black" />

                        </View>
                      </View>

                      <View style={{marginBottom:15}}>
                      {billingPreferenceDetails.isBillByEmail === 'Y' &&
                        <View>
                          <Label img={EMAIL} textLabel="Email"/>
                          <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1, marginLeft:0}}>
                            <Input
                              value={this.state.email}
                              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email:text})}
                            />
                          </Item>
                        </View>}
                        {billingPreferenceDetails.isBillBySms === 'Y' &&
                        <View>
                          <Label img={EMAIL} textLabel="SMS"/>
                          <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1, marginLeft:0}}>
                            <Input
                              value={this.state.smsNum}
                              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({smsNum:text})}
                            />
                          </Item>
                        </View>}
                        {billingPreferenceDetails.isBillByFax === 'Y' &&
                        <View>
                          <Label img={EMAIL} textLabel="FAX"/>
                          <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1, marginLeft:0}}>
                            <Input
                              value={this.state.faxNum}
                              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({faxNum:text})}
                            />
                          </Item>
                        </View>}
                      </View>

                      <View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
                        <PrimaryBtn label={'submit'} disabled={false} onPress={()=> this.OnButtonClick(this.state.preferredLanguage,this.state.preferredCurrency,
                          this.state.email,this.state.smsNum,this.state.faxNum)}/>
                      </View>
                    </Form>
                  </View>
                </View>

            </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </ImageBackground>
        );
      }
    }

    export default UpdateBillPreferences;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code have multiple checkbox,when you clicked checkbox that's value change correct,
i suggest when you clicked check box that checked value store to array using push() 
finally you access multiple checkboxs.

Answer (score 0):

If you can shorten your code sample to clarify what needs to change, it might help folks provide a more precise answer. If not, this sample function at least shows how to retrieve the `checked` status of each checkbox on the page.

The returned object has one property for each checkbox, and the property's value will be "Y" if the corresponding checkbox is checked.

```js
document.getElementById("primaryBtn").addEventListener("click", submit);

function submit(){
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']"); // Finds checkboxes
  let formData = {};
  for(let checkbox of checkboxes){
    formData[checkbox.value] = checkbox.checked ? "Y" : "N"; // Adds one property per checkbox
  }
  console.log(formData);
  return formData;
}

  // If you also want a function that notices when a checkbox changes, uncomment this:
  /*  document.addEventListener("change", handleChange);
      function handleChange(event){
        if(event.target.type && event.target.type == "checkbox"){
          console.log(event.target.value + ": " + event.target.checked);
        }
      }
  */
```

```html
<h3>Preference</h3>
<input type="checkbox" value="isBillByPost" />
<label>Post</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="isBillByEmail" />
<label>Email</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="isBillBySMS" />
<label>SMS</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="isBillByFax" />
<label>Fax</label>
<br /><br />
<button id="primaryBtn">Submit</button>
```